# Lit-Element binding to svg image. TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, lit-element, lit-html

I've been trying to bind a simple url (string) to an image tag inside a svg element.
But I am receiving following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null` and no picture is displayed in the browser.

The image as well as the binding work fine and without error inside a normal `<img>` tag or hardcoded in the `<image/>` element.

**Example with SVG:**

```
import { LitElement, svg } from 'lit-element';

class AppDevice extends LitElement {
static get properties() {
    return {
        selectedImage: {
            type: String
        }
    };
}

constructor() {
    super();
    this.selectedImage = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png';
}

render() {
    return svg`

        <svg width="600px" height="600px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

             <image xlink:href="${this.selectedImage}" id="canvas" x="176.32" y="145.932" width="252.068" height="252.068"/>
             <!-- Works -->
             <!-- <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" id="canvas" x="176.32" y="145.932" width="252.068" height="252.068"/>      -->

        </svg>

`;
}
}
```

**Example with workaround:**

After reading the discussion on github that was pointed out in the comments f this question, I've updated my answer:

[image]

```
const namespaced = directive((namespace, value) => (part) => {
       part.committer.element.setAttributeNS(namespace, part.committer.name, value);
    });

const xlinkNamespace = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png';

import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class AppDevice extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
    };
   }

constructor() {
  super();
}

render() {
   return html`

    <svg width="600px" height="600px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

      <image xlink:href="${namespaced(xlinkNamespace, 'something')}" id="canvas" x="176.32" y="145.932" width="252.068" height="252.068"/>

    </svg>

    `;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`svg` method from `lit-html`](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/api/modules/lit_html.html#svg)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @abraham. Unfortunately I was not able to get it to work. I posted another code example. Is that what you had in mind ?

Comment: That's a [issue with lit-html](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/423) not supporting namespaced attributes. There are some workarounds towards the end.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I am looking for. Not sure if I understand it though.
Looking at the codepen leaves me wondering whats the second render function is for. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQKgbE?editors=1010

Updated my answer once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wasn't able to get the example from the comments to work I came up with a different solution to my problem. Although this isn't the exact answer I was looking for, I figured that posting it here might be still a good idea.

**Without further ado here my solution:**
I made use of css clip-path to display an image inside my SVG element and in particular be able to switch it via bindings.

[Here is an article about clipping and masking](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)

```
<img .src="${this.selectedimg}" style="clip-path: url(#myClip);" width="250" height="250">

<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <rect width="250" height="250"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working, check if is a good scenario for you

```
import { html, css, svg, LitElement } from 'lit'

export class StackElement extends LitElement {

static get properties () {
    return {
        selectedImage: String
    }
}

constructor () {
    super()
    this.selectedImage = 'https://blog.mozilla.org/opendesign/files/2017/06/logo.png'
}

render () {
    return html`
        <h3>SVG image</h3>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 2523 646" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <image href=${this.selectedImage} />
        </svg>
    `
  }
}

customElements.define('stack-element', StackElement)
```